# SharePoint 2010 search result not showing document library folder icon

Tags: search-results, file-icons

Is it default behaviour that the icon next to a result showing a document library folder is a blank page? (generaldocument.gif) My customer would like to see a folder icon here and I don't understand why it isn't displayed. Just to be clear: the link shows the direct path to the folder (and not to a webpart on a page or something similar)

For example: `http://host/subsite/subsite/subsite/document library/folder/folder/folder`

How can I manage to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I had to edit the XSL of the Core Search Webpart:

I replaced this line in the original XSL: `<img align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />`

with this:

```
<div class="srch-Icon" id="{concat($currentId,'_Icon')}">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contentclass[. = 'STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary'] and isdocument[. = 'False']">
      <img align="absmiddle" src="/_layouts/images/folder.gif" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <img align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</div>
```

I got this hint from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a993cc6d-690a-439f-9db3-cf08d6a9cee4/change-the-folders-icon-displayed-in-search-results, but had to modifiy the original script a little bit to get it working.